# curtain effect on text only - text showing from middle to outer edges

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to create a curtain effect on some text. I want the text to be hidden at first and then have an animated reveal from the middle of the text to the outer edges. I want this to work even if there is an odd number of letters. In other words, breaking up the string would not work. If there is only one giant character in the string I want it to reveal from the center of the character to the outer edges of the character. I do not want a curtain effect on the background, since I don't know what I want to have for a background yet. I want it only on the text.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="my-name">The Incredible Houdini</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3vh;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
}
.my-name {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkblue;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: showName 5s linear 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes showName {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 15ch;
  }
}
```

The overflow:hidden and the width from 0 to 100 give me what I want in terms of the individual characters gradually being revealed instead of popping in like a typewriter. The problem is that it generates from the left to the right. Is there any way I can start expanding the width from the middle to the outer edges?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you would need a keyframe to `auto` width which you can't do. I'd suggest rethinking your methodology.

I'd go with animating a clip path

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25vh;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.my-name {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: .25em;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 100%);
  animation: showName 5s linear forwards;
}


@keyframes showName {
  0% {
    clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 100%);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: inset(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="my-name">The Incredible Houdini</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not really familiar with clip-path, so I will go read up on it right now!